# event machine errors out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, goliath

I am using the happening gem, a event-machine library to persist files on S3.
when i run rspec tests to "GET" a file from the aws bucket, it errors out.

Error O/P:

```
    RuntimeError: eventmachine not initialized: evma_connect_to_server
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:665:in `connect_server'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:665:in `bind_connect'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/em-http-request-1.0.3/lib/em-http/http_connection.rb:54:in `activate_connection'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/em-http-request-1.0.3/lib/em-http/http_connection.rb:89:in `setup_request'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/em-http-request-1.0.3/lib/em-http/http_connection.rb:4:in `get'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/happening-0.2.5/lib/happening/s3/request.rb:35:in `execute'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/happening-0.2.5/lib/happening/s3/item.rb:44:in `get'\
```

Has any body faced a similar issue ?

thakns

Answer (score 0):

This could be solved by adding `with_api` block

```rb
  it "should return pong response" do
    with_api API do
      get_request(path: "/api/ping") do |async|
        async.response.should == { ping: "pong" }.to_json
      end
    end
  end
```

where `API` is your api class which inherits from `Goliath::API`

And to `spec_helper.rb` add:

```
require 'goliath/test_helper'
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.include Goliath::TestHelper, :example_group => {
    :file_path => /spec\/api/
  }
end
```